# Find the value of $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}}{2}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}}}{2}...$?

Tags: radicals, substitution

How to find the value of $\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \cdot \dfrac{\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}}{2}\cdot \dfrac{\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}}}{2}...$?

> I can notice that, $a_{n-1} = 2(a_n)^2 -1$

> This will further imply that, $a_n = \sqrt{\dfrac{a_{n-1} + 1}{2}}$

> I'm thinking of relating this general term with the cosine identity.
> $\cos(\frac{x}{2})= \sqrt{\frac{1 +\cos x}{2}}$

> Also I can notice that, $a_1 = \dfrac{2\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})}{2}$

Can we conclude anything from the above points?

Comment: This is [Vieta's formula for $2/\pi$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_Formula_for_Pi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found that $$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{a_n+1}{2}}$$ and $a_1=\cos\frac{\pi}{4}$

Let $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Therefore using this the product becomes

$$P=\cos x \cos \frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{4}\cos \frac{x}{8}...$$

We can calculate $P$ by taking limiting value of $P_n$where

$$P_n=\cos x \cos \frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{4}\cos \frac{x}{8}...\cos\dfrac{x}{2^n}=\frac{\sin2x}{2^{n+1}\sin\frac{x}{2^n}}$$

$$P=\lim_{n \to \infty}P_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}*2)}{2^{n+1}\sin\frac{\pi}{2^{n+2}}}=\frac{2}{\pi}$$

Comment: How did you get cos x/2 cosx/4 ...? Can explain please?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, we found that $a_1=\cos\frac{\pi}{4}$ and also the relation $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{a_n+1}{2}}$, therefore using this $a_2=\sqrt{\frac{a_1+1}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{\cos\frac{\pi}{4}+1}{2}}=\cos\frac{\pi}{8}$ , btw which part of world you belong to?